# Print space-separated list in columns

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have this Makefile that has a variables named "MODULES" which lists all the modules I have activated in my build.

This list is separated by spaces, so it looks like this when I do `echo $(MODULES)`:

```
module1 module2 module3 module4 mod5 mod6 mod7 module8 module9
```

What I would like to do is present this list in some columns that would be displayed at compilation time.

Like this:

```
Modules activated:
module1 module2 module3 
module4 mod5    mod6 
mod7    module8 module9
```

Ideally, the column withs would adjust to the width of the largest module in the column (see `mod7`); and the number of columns would be adjusted according to the width of the current terminal.

Now, I found some unix utilities that seem to do that, like [column](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_column.htm), but I can't make it work with my set.

Do you have some trick that would allow me to do that?

**edit**:

With the answer chosen below, I finally cracked this command in my Makefile:

```
@printf '%s\n' $(MODULES) | sort | column
```

Comment: What are empirically realistic module name lengths?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
printf '%-12s%-12s%s\n' $modules
```

This consumes the contents of the variable for the number of times a placeholder appears in the format string and repeats until all the contents are consumed.

The `column` utility will automatically produce columns for you:

```
column <<< "$(printf '%s\n' $module)"
```

That's column-first. If you want row-first:

```
column -x <<< "$(printf '%s\n' $module)"
```

Comment: +1 Nice!  I think you wanted another `12` before the last `s`.  Only problem is that it always uses 3 columns, regardless of terminal width.

Comment: @RobI: Actually, I wanted dashes to left-justify the fields - then a width isn't needed for the last field. I missed the OP's requirement regarding the terminal width. I'll edit my answer to cover both.

Comment: That's perfect. I didn't know about `printf`! Anyway, my Makefile command is: `@printf '%s\n' $(MODULES) | sort | column` and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Using the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014908/how-to-output-an-arrays-content-in-columns-in-bash), try something like this:

```
echo "Modules activated:"
for item in $modules; do 
    printf "%-8s\n" "${item}"
done | column
```

Potentially adding `-x` to the column command if you want to transpose the output.

This should be terminal-sensitive in terms of the # of columns.

Answer (score 1):

Aligned with `column` and `fold`:

```
echo $modules | column -t | fold | column -t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fold and tab, to get some rough formatting:

```
echo "module1 module2 module3 module4 mod5 mod6 mod7 module8 module9" | sed 's/ /\t/g' | fold -s -18module1 module2 
module3 module4 
mod5    mod6    
mod7    module8 
module9
```

but it will not work properly if some modulenames are longer than 8 characters, and some are shorter.