# How to output a bash array into multiple columns of numbered items

Tags: arrays, bash

The following script outputs a numbered list of items.

```
#!/bin/bash

menu=( $(ls ${HOME}) )
i=0
for m in ${menu[@]}
do 
    echo  "$(( i++ ))) $m"
done
```

The result:

```
0) item
1) item
2) item
3) item
```

I would like to split that list into multiple columns so more data fits on one page. Simply piping to column `echo  "$(( i++ ))) $m" | column` still results in a single column only now every line begins with `0)` followed by the item listed.

The answers given in [How to output an array's content in columns in BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014908/how-to-output-an-arrays-content-in-columns-in-bash) work as far as making multiple columns of output.

```
menu=( $(ls $HOME) )
echo " ${menu[@]/%/$'\n'}" | column
```

But because the array is quoted, using the bash arithmetic method `i=0; echo "$(( i++ ))"` doesn't work for numbering as the only number output is the first `0`.

My question is: How can I output the data from an array into an numbered list of multiple columns?

```
0) item        4) item        8) item
1) item        5) item        9) item
2) item        6) item       10) item
3) item        7) item       11) item
```

Comment: Your code has multiple issues when it comes to filenames containing whitespace or shell metacharacters. [Don't use `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [quote everything](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable). Anyway looks like you are actually looking simply for `select file in "$HOME"/*`

Comment: I know you are correct. In this particular example though I am certain that none of the filenames contain any whitespace or metacharacters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added few changes to your original script, now `xargs` and `column -t` will divide the line after every three records and then `column -t` will indentate it properly. Avoid using `ls` to get the file list.

```
#!/bin/bash

menu=( $HOME/* )
i=0
for m in ${menu[@]}
do
    echo  "$(( i++ ))) $(basename $m)"
done |xargs -L3 |column -t
```

Sample output:

```
0)   Desktop      1)   Documents  2)   Downloads
3)   Music        4)   Pictures   5)   Public
6)   Templates    7)   XXX        8)   Videos
9)   backup_XXXX  10)  dna        11)  scripting
12)  sessions     13)  sh         14)  temp
```

Comment: how can you do this where 0-4 are an the same column?

Answer (score 3):

How about you print it out single column and pipe it to `pr`:

```
$ for i in {0..11}; do echo $i ; done|pr -ts" " --columns 3
0 4 8
1 5 9
2 6 10
3 7 11
```

Comment: Well, do you have a stray `-` in `ps`'s parameters? What are you using... as an OS I mean?

Comment: I copied what is written verbatim `for i in {0..11}; do echo $i ; done|pr -ts" " --columns 3`. I am using Mac OS X.

Comment: I don't have a Mac available. Any Mac users who can `man pr`? `--columns` probably has an alias.

Comment: The man page shows an option for `-column`. "Produce output that is columns wide (default is 1) that is written vertically down each column in the order in which the text is received from the input file.  The options -e and -i are assumed.  This option should not be used with -m.  When used with -t, the minimum number of lines is used to display the output." Still getting error "illegal option -- c"

Comment: Well, I would use `-column 3`instead of `--columns 3` then.

Comment: sorry i should have been clear. Using `-column 3` results in "illegal option --c"

Comment: Sorry, can't help anymore as I don't have a Mac. You just have to fight it, man--take one for the community and document it here so that the next one @user556068+1 will have it easier!

Comment: No problem. I appreciate your help

Comment: You are misreading the [man page](http://ss64.com/osx/pr.html).  It says -*colums* which should be read out as e.g. `-3` for three columns.  Indeed `printf '%s\n' {0..11} | pr -ts" " -3` works portably on both OSX and Linux.

Comment: ... However, the `-s" "` isn't going to work very well if you have variable-width items.  Try just `pr -t3` or maybe pipe to `column` instead, which has a slightly different feature set.